# Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html when inject angular-route.map

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-service, angularjs-routing

What could be the cause of error in dependency injection of ngRouteProvider

NOTE: $location has a dependency on ngRoute, thats why I need to inject it, while, I am not really using it, but $location only.

I embed the necessary js file into my php file by:

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="/library/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="/library/angularjs/1.2.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="/library/angularjs/1.2.9/angular-route.min.js.map"></script>
<script src="/library/angular-ui/bootstrap/0.11.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
```

I inject the modules into my module by:

```
var VPPContractsApp = angular.module('VPPContractsApp', ['ui.bootstrap','$location','$window'])
                             .controller('VPPContractsController', VPPContractsController);

function VPPContractsController($scope,$http,$modal,$location,$window){../})
```

Error message I received looks like:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "/library/angularjs/1.2.9/angular-route.min.js.map". myfile.php:10
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Inside the .map file when chrome inspector reported at the first line and begaining of the whole file (the actual file content is different where it is downloaded and reference from our own server's /library folder.)

[image]

I searched through everywhere can't find a proper solution.

**What not gonna work:**
1.Change text/javascript into application/javascript.

2.File Permission,I downloaded it directly from the official site:https://code.angularjs.org/

**==========update 1**

I keep receiving error in inspector

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module VPPContractsApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module $window due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module '$window' is not available! You either misspelled the...<omitted>...1)
```

and seems it deal with how to put the injecting service ( except 'ui.bootstrap', but any other service ('$window','$resource','$location') all will call out error, and which ever will be called above error first if I switching around which to inject first. (i.e. if I place $resource before $window, the error will be about '$resource' not '$window'.

I wonder why they think they are not exist while I already loaded both angular-route and angular-resource?

Comment: You have to remove this line: `<script type="application/javascript" src="/library/angularjs/1.2.9/angular-route.min.js.map"></script>`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the error message says a bit more ... I hope you deleted the `.map` script and not accidentally the other one.

Comment: Did you include angularUI bootstrap somewhere? It seems that it is missing.

Comment: What I mean is that your code includes `<script ... angular.min.js` and `<script ... angular-route.min.js`, but I don't see bootstrap.

Comment: If it's possible then replace the minified version of angular with the regular one. That would give you a more useful error message.

Comment: @zeroflagL WOW.... THAT SOLVED EVERYTHING!!! GOSH!!! soo much more detail, I never knew that unminified version shows so much detail lol. Thank man, you made the day :)

Comment: @zeroflagL Seem the problem is deeper or some spot I missed, I update the question could you help me on this? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
angular.module('VPPContractsApp', ['ui.bootstrap','$location','$window']
```

`$location` and `$window` are no modules. They are services provided by angular by default. You don't need to include a module to use them. You can delete those two here.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes this issue is caused by referencing a javascript file without specifying the type of it .. make sure to always include the type in script tags

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="...."></script>
```